# Nodemailer error (Error: queryA EREFUSED)

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, nodemailer

***sorry for my english***

I am using nodemailer and when querying through the api it gives this error:

```
    Error: queryA EREFUSED smtp.gmail.com
        at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:210:19) {
      errno: undefined,
      code: 'EDNS',
      syscall: 'queryA',
      hostname: 'smtp.gmail.com',
      command: 'CONN'
    }
```

My code:

```
    this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: 'gmail'
      auth: {
        user: mygmail@gmail.com,
        pass: mypass,
      },
})
```

UPD: I connected the phone to the Internet instead of my LAN cable, checked, everything worked. There was no error, I connected the LAN back, disconnected the phone, this error appeared again

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `Less secure app access` is on in your Gmail account:

[Less secure app access](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) > ON

Then fix your code:

```
this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: email,
    pass: password
  }
});
```

Comment: Less secure app access ON

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in service in the Nodemailer and make your code simpler with this one.

```
this.transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: mygmail@gmail.com,
    pass: mypass,
  },
})
```

Please make sure you have disabled 2-Step verification.

Comment: i dont have 2 step verification